# Need a PHP or Javascript delay for IMG

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need something to help with my local production of some IMG loaders that I made with jQuery. They work fine on the web after I empty my browser's cache but local testing is just too fast to see the loading animation while the image is downloading.

So what I need is something to delay the IMG from loading for a specified amount of time. Not just a timeout function on the img loaders I made.

Maybe something like this to delay the img load for 5 seconds. Something in PHP would probably be preferred, I'm not sure. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
<img src="photo.jpg?delay5" />
```

@Jamund and @Brad both answered this correctly. I added my own take to make the script a bit leaner with the help of the built-in function GETIMAGESIZE :

The HTML

```
<!-- HTML-->
<a href="idelay.php?file=poster.jpg"><img src="th_poster.jpg"  width="100" /></a>
```

The PHP

```
<?php 
// contents of idelay.php (image delay)
$file = $_GET['file'];
$absolutePath = 'http://demos.lap/assets/photos/celebrities/';
$imginfo = getimagesize($absolutePath.$file);
$mimeinfo = $imginfo['mime']; //without curly braces if not calling directly such as in this variable

//header("Content-type: {$imginfo['mime']}");
header("Content-type: $mimeinfo");
sleep(5);
readfile($absolutePath.$file);

?>
```

Comment: php will not help, its server side.

Comment: Not sure about this but do downloadable web servers like xampp allow you to emulate a live environment in terms of load times etc?

Comment: @MartyWallace Not that I know of. If they do I sure would like to know where this option is for MAMP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution #1 (basic idea using PHP)

My PHP is a little out of date, but this is the basic idea.

**HTML**

`<img src="slow.php?path=image.jpg">`

**PHP**

```
$path = $_GET['path'];
sleep(1); // 1 second
header('image/png');
readfile($path); // may need to do something fancier to get the right path
```

### Solution #2 (using jQuery)

This approach may need some tweaking to not clash with your plugin, but it should work.

**HTML**

`<img src="image.jpg">`

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $("img").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var src = $this.attr("src");
    $this.attr("src", ""); // remove image
    setTimeout(function() {
      $this.attr("src", src); // add back after a second
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

Comment: I will add my own take on it but it works just great as is. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Failing the other options (if you have access to the internet from this machine) you could just link to a large image from a remote server.

Comment: yes but once it's cached, i would have to link to another large image or empty cache. I could also rename the file on the remote server but all not optimal I'm afraid

Comment: @JoelZ. You could temporarily add a timestamp to the image while your developing, so in each call call something like image.jpg?time=123456789. Then when you're done developing, remove that little line of code. Each time you add a timestamp, it *should* force the browser to clear the cache of the image and re-download it.

Comment: Yes that would be better and I have made something like that with php that adds a time stamp at the end of the img src but still looking for something that only works with a remote server.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a custom delay code. You need an HTTP throttler.

There's one built in [Charles, an HTTP debugging proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/). I once accidentally hit a throttling hotkey and was suffering for 3 hours, blaming my ISP. :)

Here's a screenshot of its settings:[image: Charles throttling settings]

Comment: Very cool. Kinda high on the price for what I would use it for but I do see this tool is much more of use for other more important development things. I'll bookmark it for future reference. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

An http throttler seems like a cleaner solution, but if you end up going the PHP script route, you can do something like this:

```
<!-- your html -->
<img src="/somescript.php?file=myimage.jpg" />


<?php
//contents of somescript.php

$file = $_GET['file'];
$absolutePath = '/absolute/directory/where/images/live/';

$contents = file_get_contents($absolutePath.$file);
if(function_exists('finfo_buffer')) { 
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mimeType = $finfo->buffer($contents);
}else {
    $extension = array_pop(explode('.', $file));
    $mimeTypes = array(
        'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
        'png' => 'image/png'
    );
    $mimeType = $mimeTypes[$extension];
}

sleep(5);
header('Content-Type: '. $mimeType);
echo $contents;
```

Comment: I added the missing ?> at the end of your code but still doesn't work.  I have changed the absolute path accordingly. I do get the 5 second delay but image doesn't load and don't see an error.

Comment: I tried typing it directly on the location bar of the browser. http://localhost/testing/img-loader/somescript.php?file=desert.jpg but get a file download prompt from the browser to download file named somescript.php

Comment: I had the absolute path wrong by by own mistake. Works well but I can only choose one answer. Thank you for answer

Comment: I never close php tags, no need to if you're separating your markup from your php, and alleviates a lot of issues that can arise if you close them and leave spaces after them.

Answer (score 0):

Have a PHP script set the appropriate header for the image format, delay for a given amount of time (check `$_GET` for the value given in the querystring), and then `readfile()` the actual image. Oh, and set the PHP script as the `src` in the image tag.

Comment: I agree with your methodology but I think it does imply a rewrite rule no?

Comment: @grifos: Nope. As long as you have the right Content-Type header, the browser won't care.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but didn't meant on client side, but on server side. I mean have to create a rewrite rule so that jpg image suffix ending url call in fact an image loading php script.

Comment: Sure, i locked my mind to keep the url intact =). Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Like Dagon said php in your case is a server side langage, so it won't solve your problem because when your browser hit the cache it won't call a php script.

On the other hand you can create a javascript function that will be called client side and that load the image. You will then have full control on when you want the image to be displayed.

Regards